# Why MQTT Android drains battery?

Tags: battery, mqtt

i have developed mqtt service on android device, the service work fine, reach notify, and in WIFI the battery is not drained, but when i pass on 3g network the service drain more battery over 40% in wifi is arround 3% the battery drains,
on low profile phones the problem not appear the service in 3g network drains arround 10% of battery, i have see it drain more battery on 4.4.2 Andorid version.. can help me?

p.s. i use paho client!

Answer (score 1):

The MQTT client needs to send a keep-alive message every so often to maintain the connection channel and also to let the server know it’s still connected. Maybe the connection option "keepalive" is too short and it's draining the battery.

Try other keepalive settings and change publish, and subscribe message to QoS0. QoS1 and QoS2 get more traffic.

More details: http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/219